# strip string from column that contains JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
  details
0 {"id":123,"code":"","name":"abc123","email":"test1@gmail.com","status":"good"}
1 {"id":124,"code":"","name":"abc456","email":"test2@gmail.com","status":"bad"}
```

I am looking to strip out `abc123` and `abc456` for each of the rows in this dataframe, the data type is currently an object. I've tried to convert to a string and strip and the used the following:

```
lambda x: x.lstrip('name"":""').rstrip('"",""email"":'))
```

But it does not capture the values.

The expected output should be a dataframe with just the code values:

```
  code
0 abc123f
1 abc456
```

What would be the best method to accomplish the above question?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `json.loads`:

```
import json

df['code'] = df['details'].apply(lambda x: json.loads(x).get('name'))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                                             details    code
0  {"id":123,"code":"","name":"abc123","email":"t...  abc123
1  {"id":124,"code":"","name":"abc456","email":"t...  abc456
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
>>> df['code'] = df.pop('details').str['name']
>>> df
     code
0  abc123
1  abc456
>>>
```

Or if the dictionaries are strings:

```
>>> df['code'] = df.pop('details').str.extract(r"'name': '(.*?)'")
>>> df
     code
0  abc123
1  abc456
>>>
```